# After updating Dart its showing "Configuration ' (Flutter)' is missing in 'launch.json'."

Tags: flutter, dart

I opened vs code and it said "Your Dart Code is Updated" to version 3.something; but after that I can't run my app it gives me error

> Configuration 'NameOfApp (Flutter)' is missing in 'launch.json'.

What should i do

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Goto Run in vscode then click on Add Configuration option. Thats all now you can run your app without any problem.

Comment: strange, it just added an empty line and solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Open VS [ `Code` > `Run` > `Add Configuration` .

Finally run your app! It must works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the indenting of the code inside lunch.json.

Sometimes if you copy/paste the launch.json file from another project or source you might have an extra column that breaks vs code debug process. At least that was my case!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the launch.json and ran the app again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I updated my Flutter(v 3.16.2) and Dart(v3.2.2) to the latest just this morning and the issue ended up being the iOS Simulator. All I had to do was manually launch it and select the device I wanted to use and things started working!!

Answer (score 0):

Open VS [ Code > Run > Add Configuration ]
my config.json =

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter Attach",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter Web",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--web-port",
                "8000"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).